# How can use responsive html in avada theme?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, responsive

Heloo
How can use html/css cod in avada theme wordpress by responsive?

Please see this image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add @media for your css for both screens inside your html with the tag  inside your html code!

Answer (score 0):

This is cod.

```html
<style>
div.cities {
    background-color: #ecf0f1;
    color: #000;
     border:3px solid #bdc0c1;
     border-style:dashed; }
.clear {clear: both}
.flex{ display:flex;margin: 20px; padding: 20px 0 0 0;}
.flex img{
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
 margin: 0 10px;
}
 .flex strong {font: 14px isans-light; color: #4c4b51;}
 .flex p {width: 145px; height: 40px;color: #8d8d8d;font: 12px isans-light}
 
 
</style>
<div class="cities">

<div class="flex">
  <img  src="wp-content/uploads/2017/01/f-01.png"/>
  <div>
  
  <strong>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing

</strong>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
  </div>
 <img  src="wp-content/uploads/2017/01/f-02.png"/>
  <div><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</strong>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
  </div>
  <img  src="wp-content/uploads/2017/01/f-03.png"/>
  <div><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing </strong>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</p>
  </div>
  
  <img  src="wp-content/uploads/2017/01/f-4.png"/>
  <div><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing</strong>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing </p>
  </div>
  
  
  
  
  
</div>

</div>
```